# how can i totally remove decorators from my react-native project?

Tags: react-native, decorator, babeljs, mobx

i just started learning react-native recently and i tried to use babel decorators and i kept getting this error...

index.js: The 'decorators' plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option, whose value must be a boolean. If you are migrating from Babylon/Babel 6 or want to use the old decorators proposal, you should use the 'decorators-legacy' plugin instead of 'decorators'.

RCTFatal
**28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
main
start
0x0

[check out the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLcdo.jpg)

[image]

please i would like to know how to successfully integrate mobx decorators with babel7.6.0 and above into my react native project or how i can completely remove the error above from my react native app because the error has refused to go even after i uninstalled @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators and other plugins i installed initially